# Reverse a string with java but not completely

Tags: java, string, reverse

I need a java program which reverse a string

for e.g.:-

input:-"hello world"
output:- "world hello"

Comment: what you have tried..?

Comment: There is a magical information source available on the Internet; try accessing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ and read the String page.

Comment: i just want to reverse a string but not completly

Comment: @DwB java built in function reverse() completely reverse the string that i don't want to

Comment: @MiteshSondhi  Heads up, when I say read a page, I mean "read the page", not "skim the page"

Comment: This should be your global function: `    public static String sentence(String s) {

        String[] before = s.split(" ");
        String after = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
            after += (before[before.length - i - 1] + " ");
        }

        return after;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split(" ")` to split the String into words (i.e. breaking on spaces). Then iterate over the resulting array of words and build up the reverse by prepending each word to a StringBuilder.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverseOrderOfWords("hello world"));
}

public static String reverseOrderOfWords(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : s.split(" ")) {
        sb.insert(0, word + " ");
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Produces:

```
world hello
```

Answer (score 3):

Split the string via `split()` method and space delimiter. It will return the array of the words in the string, then reverse the array and concatenate elements via space character. That's all.